# Delete auto deployed charts by using gitlabs tiller instance?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I am using the Gitlab Auto DevOps CI pipeline and I want to remove a deployment using helm.

I try to connect to tiller like this `helm init --client-only --tiller-namespace=gitlab-managed-apps` which results in

`$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/marvin/.helm.
Not installing Tiller due to 'client-only' flag having been set
Happy Helming!`

`helm list --namespace=gitlab-managed-apps`returns `Error: could not find tiller`

Comment: export TILLER_NAMESPACE=gitlab-managed-apps - this allows the helm client to talk to the tiller installed on that namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I've found the solution to list releases here : https://forum.gitlab.com/t/orphaned-apps-in-gitlab-managed-apps-namespace/22717/9

```
export TILLER_NAMESPACE="gitlab-managed-apps"

kubectl get secrets/tiller-secret -n "$TILLER_NAMESPACE" -o "jsonpath={.data['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode > tiller-ca.crt
kubectl get secrets/tiller-secret -n "$TILLER_NAMESPACE" -o "jsonpath={.data['tls\.crt']}" | base64 --decode > tiller.crt
kubectl get secrets/tiller-secret -n "$TILLER_NAMESPACE" -o "jsonpath={.data['tls\.key']}" | base64 --decode > tiller.key

helm list --tiller-connection-timeout 30 --tls --tls-ca-cert tiller-ca.crt --tls-cert tiller.crt --tls-key tiller.key --all --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps
```

You can then run :

```
helm delete <name> [--purge] --tiller-connection-timeout 30 --tls --tls-ca-cert tiller-ca.crt --tls-cert tiller.crt --tls-key tiller.key --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps
```

Edit:

@mrvnklm proposed to use -D options for base64. In my case, it doesn't work anymore with "d" uppercased. After checks, I guess it's for macOs users([man page base64 osx](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/base64/)). For linux, it seems to be "-d" ([man page linux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64)). Changed to "--decode" according to mrvnklm's comment.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You could also use `--decode` so it would work on both platforms

Answer (score 1):

As you did a "client-only" `helm --init`, helm doesn't know how to find the correct `tiller` instance.

You need to specify where the tiller is in your subsequent calls to `helm list`.

This is touched upon in the helm install documentation [here](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#running-tiller-locally). You will either need to set `HELM_HOST` environment variable, or add `--host` to every call. You will also need to specify (and have access to) any TLS certificates used to make the Gitlab Auto DevOps connection.

Comment: Okay, after setting the TILLER_NAMESPACE I get a `Error: transport is closing` which seems to be an issue related to permissions or certificates?
Is there a way I can get the certs that gitlab uses to communicate with tiller?

Comment: Yes, that's the error you would get if you call `helm` with TLS not properly configured. Not sure where Gitlab stores the TLS certs and how/if you can easily get at them.